# drawing a rect with opencv on a frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a frame and want to draw a rectangle in specefic position a rectangle with:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<conio.h>

 int main () {
cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("cmd.png");
    cvRectangle(
            &frame,
            cvPoint(5,10),
            cvPoint(20,30),
            cvScalar(255,255,255)
       );
     cv::imshow("test " , frame);
while (cv::waitKey() != 23) ;
return 1; 
 }
```

wenn I run the code I get a memory error.

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x000007fefd42caed in OpenCV_capture.exe: Microsoft C++ 
exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0018ead0..
```

Any idea why do I get this, and how can I solve it

Comment: Are you sure the values max.x and max.y are within the bounds of the frame?

Comment: yes I'm sure, the are the max is the a point from the frame

Comment: I just made a test with an other code and it dind't work as well:( , I'm doing something wrong ? see my edited question

Comment: Can you step through your program with a debugger it and see at which line the error occurs ?

Comment: the declaration of cvRectangle is the problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're mixing up the C++ API with the C API. Use the rectangle function in the "cv" namespace instead of "cvRectangle":

```
cv::rectangle(
    frame,
    cv::Point(5, 10),
    cv::Point(20, 30),
    cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255)
);
```

Furthermore, you're trying to display the image in a window that you didn't open:

```
int main() {
    cv::namedWindow("test ");

    // ...
```

If the image did not load properly, this might also cause an error because you're then trying to draw onto an empty image.

```
if (frame.data != NULL) {
    // Image successfully loaded
    // ...
```

Comment: Note that you can check if `cv::Mat frame` is loaded correctly by checking `frame.empty()`

Answer (score 2):

This Code works :

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
int main()
{
//Window 
cvNamedWindow("Drawing",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//Image loading
IplImage* original=cvLoadImage("i.jpg");
 if(Original==NULL ) 
{
    puts("ERROR: Can't upload frame");
    exit(0);
}

cvRectangle(original,cvPoint(100,50),cvPoint(200,200),CV_RGB(255,0,0),5,8);

 //Showing the image
 cvShowImage("Drawing",original);

 cvWaitKey(0);
 //CleanUp
 cvReleaseImage(&original);
 cvDestroyAllWindows();

}
```